# How to make local notifications with flutter?

Tags: flutter, web-scraping, mobile, notifications

I need to make an app that, every 15 minutes checks a website and, if something changed. I am trying to find a way to push notifications. I looked at flutter_local_notifications but couldnt find an example to see it working properly.

Does anyone knows a way to do an app like this properly with flutter?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [background_fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch) plugin which can hit your code when the app is closed about every 15 minutes and you could use the [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) to schedule notifications when the app is not running in foreground, background or closed. The examples provided in the above link is working.

But that's not the case with some device models of manufacture's like Xiaomi, Redmi, Letv, Honor, Oppo, Vivo etc. There you need to get the `AutoStart` permission to make this work when the app is closed. And taking this permission differs from manufacturer to manufacturer where the popular app like WhatsApp are already provided with AutoStart permission by the Manufacturer itself.

So you can use [autostart](https://pub.dev/packages/autostart) flutter library which uses a native Android library called [AutoStarter](https://github.com/judemanutd/AutoStarter) for taking permission from such devices.